# JavaScript innerHTML does not show up

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code.

```
var warning = '<div class="ui inline cookie nag style="display: block;"><span class="title">Tava ekrāna rezolūcija ir pārāk maza, lai skatītu šo lapu. Lūdzu, palielini rezolūciju vai attālini lapu!</span><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw" style="color: #eee; float:right"></i></div>';

document.getElementById("resWarn").innerHTML = warning;
```

Nothing is showing up, when putting script into html page.
Script is included UNDER `<span  id="resWarn"></span>`. When I set variable `warning` to anything like `sdnhasjkshushduig`, it show up.

Please help.

Comment: Code is fine and works.

Comment: Basicly `div` is invalid content within a [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span).

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7b0mdjL0/

Comment: Perhaps you forgot the window.onload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a quote after -> "nag"

```
class="ui inline cookie nag"
```

Comment: Than you! My mistake.

Comment: If this was the answer, mark it as answer please... :)

Comment: Yes, I'll do. I'll be able to do this after 3 minutes. Thanks again.

Comment: If you need any help just leave a comment... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to put quotation marks before the keyword *style*.

Like this:

```
var warning = '<div class="ui inline cookie nag" style="display: block;"><span class="title">Tava ekrāna rezolūcija ir pārāk maza, lai skatītu šo lapu. Lūdzu, palielini rezolūciju vai attālini lapu!</span><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw" style="color: #eee; float:right"></i></div>';
```